# Is it possible to run 2 AsyncTasks and with one interface onResult Listener that return obtained data to the main thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Okey, first of all sorry for my level of Engish. I have an Activity that I want to show the content of two differents Lists(RecyclerViews), In this moment I only have one AsyncTask that returns to the main thread the downloaded data with an interface between the AsyncTask and Activity.

With this, I can show the data downloaded in the first RecyclerView, but i want to   show the other data that I need to download in the other RecyclerView.
So with one interface that return a string of data when AsyncTask finish (onPostExecute method) How can I differentiate the received data from the first AsynkTask to the Second, and how can i do differents actions (add the data to first RecyclerView or the Second). I can duplicate the same AsyncTask and the Interface and change the names, but i think that this isn't the correct way.

Hope you can Help me please!

**Interface:**

```
public interface ResultsListener {
    public void onResultsSucceeded(String result);
}
```

**AsynkTask**:

```
public class AsyncTaskHttpRequests extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>      {
private String response;
private String tipus_request;
private Map<String, String> parameters;
ResultsListener listener;

public AsyncTaskHttpRequests(String tipus) {
    tipus_request = tipus;
}

public AsyncTaskHttpRequests(Map<String, String> params, String tipus) {
    this.parameters = params;
    tipus_request = tipus;
}

public void setOnResultsListener(ResultsListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    Integer result = 0;
    try {
        String url = params[0];
        if (tipus_request.equals("GET")) {
            String paramet = getGETDataString(parameters);
            url = url + paramet;
            Log.e("Fck", url);
        }

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod(tipus_request);
        // no deixa validar aixo: urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (tipus_request.equals("POST")) {
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(getPostDataString(parameters));
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
        }
        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
        if (statusCode == 200) {

            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);


            result = 1; // Successful

        } else {
            result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        /* Download complete. Lets update UI */
    if (result == 1) {
        listener.onResultsSucceeded(response);
        Log.e("Si", "S'han baixat dades");
    } else {
        Log.e("No", "Error al baixar dades");
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ResultsListener {

private RecyclerView RecView;
private Search_Adapter myAppAdapter;
private ArrayList<Search_Cancons> postArrayList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    RecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_search);
    RecView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    postArrayList=new ArrayList<Search_Cancons>();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    RecView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    myAppAdapter=new Search_Adapter(postArrayList,getFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext());
    RecView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
}

public void onResultsSucceeded(String result) {
    try {

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        String resultat_JSON = response.getString("status");
        if (resultat_JSON.equals("ok")) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject canco = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject nom_artista = canco.optJSONObject("artista");
                String titol_canco = canco.getString("titol");
                String nom_artista_s = nom_artista.getString("nom");
                postArrayList.add(new Search_Cancons("http://provajson.esy.es/c1.png", titol_canco, nom_artista_s));
                RecView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);

            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public AsyncTaskHttpRequests(String tipus, String type /* add type parameter*/) {
    //create this object with type parameter that came from activity
    tipus_request = tipus;
    this.type = type; //
}   

public interface ResultsListener {
    //add type parameter
    public void onResultsSucceeded(String type, String result);
}
```

And

```
if (result == 1) {
    listener.onResultsSucceeded(type, response);
    Log.e("Si", "S'han baixat dades");
}
```

In the activity:

```
@Override
public void onResultsSucceeded(String type, String result) {
    switch(type) {} //use type variable
}
```